# Pandas Series Groupby Month and Day Average for All Years

Tags: pandas, date, average, series

imagine i have a pandas series "ylt" of shape (10775,) that looks like this with "time" in the form yyyy-mm-dd :

```
time
1991-01-01    10.949402
1991-01-02    16.236185
1991-01-03    17.167771
1991-01-04    12.314729
1991-01-05    14.761183
```

I need to find the daily average of "ylt" by month for all years (1991-2020) for this data so that the final averaged data looks like this with the "time" column in format mm-dd form:

```
time     
01-01    9.563174
01-02    8.678204
01-03    10.390276
```

I have tried different options of "groupby" options and I keep getting different errors. Thank you in advance. Here below is one of my attempts to group on the index "time" by month and day for all years:

```
lty = ylt.groupby(ylt.index.month,ylt.index.day).mean()
```

Error message:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'Int64Index'
```

Comment: If you groupby multiple things they should to be within a list: `lt.groupby([ylt.index.month, ylt.index.day]).mean()`

Comment: Hi - thanks for this - works perfectly!